# Button onClick() function active class not correctly performing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, onclick

In this code, I wanted each buttons to show each content section when they are clicked. I set up the active state of each button and it is supposed to add active class to the button which is clicked, but when I added switch statement to show the content of the button, buttons' active state also showed some issued like showing 2/3 active buttons at the same time. Here's my code.

```
import React from 'react'

export default function CourseSection() {
    const[tab, openTab] = React.useState(null);

    let prevClickedBtn = null; //To allocate the id of the previously clicked button

    const sectionBtns = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Video', icon_class: 'fa-solid fa-play', btn_name: 'video' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Lab', icon_class: 'fa-solid fa-check', btn_name: 'lab' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Note', icon_class: 'fa-regular fa-note-sticky', btn_name: 'note' },
        { id: 4, name: 'Chat', icon_class: 'fa-regular fa-comment-dots', btn_name: 'chat' },
    ]


    const ClickedSectionButton = (event) => {
        const getClickedBtn = event.target.id;
        const getClickedBtnName = event.target.name;
        const clickedButton = document.getElementById(getClickedBtn);
        clickedButton.classList.add('active');
        switch (getClickedBtnName) {
            case 'video':
                openTab(0)
                break;

            case 'lab':
                openTab(1)
                break;

            case 'note':
                openTab(2)
                break;

            case 'chat':
                openTab(3)
                break;
    
            default:
                break;
        }
        if (prevClickedBtn !== null) {
            prevClickedBtn.classList.remove('active');
        }
   
        prevClickedBtn = clickedButton;

        console.log('tab:'+tab+'\n');
    }

    return (
        <div className='course_section'>
            <div className='section_button_container'>
                {sectionBtns.map(({ id, icon_class, name, btn_name }) => {
                    return (
                        <div className='course_btns' key={id}>
                            <button
                                type='button'
                                className='section_btn'
                                name={btn_name}
                                id={`button${id}`}
                                onClick={ClickedSectionButton}
                            >
                                <i className={icon_class}></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                {name}
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
            </div>

            <div className='data_container'>
                {tab===0 && <><h1>Video Section</h1></>}
                {tab===1 && <><h1>Lab Section</h1></>}
                {tab===2 && <><h1>Note Section</h1></>}
                {tab===3 && <><h1>Chat Section</h1></>}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

CodeSanbox link for my full code to better understand the issue of my code!
https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-framework-g4osdi?file=/src/styles.css

Before clicking, the buttons don't have any active class but after clicking each of them, they simultaneously show active class on each button even though the content already changed. I have to click at least thrice for the buttons to remove its active class.

Comment: Try to log `prevClickedBtn` after `let prevClickedBtn=null;` when you click on the button you will see the log `null`. And that's because of React will run your function component when render and re-render so after you change the text section React do re-render and your `prevClickedBtn` is reset to `null`. If you want to hold the variable you have to use Ref.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the many reasons why querying and mutating the DOM is anti-pattern in React.

For each button's `onClick` handler just set the `tab` state to the `id` value of the button that was clicked, and conditionally apply the `"active"` classname if the currently mapped button's `id` matches the `tab` state value.

Example:

```
import React from "react";

const sectionBtns = [
  { id: 1, name: "Video", icon_class: "fa-solid fa-play", btn_name: "video" },
  { id: 2, name: "Lab", icon_class: "fa-solid fa-check", btn_name: "lab" },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Note",
    icon_class: "fa-regular fa-note-sticky",
    btn_name: "note"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Chat",
    icon_class: "fa-regular fa-comment-dots",
    btn_name: "chat"
  }
];

export default function CourseSection() {
  const [tab, openTab] = React.useState(null);

  return (
    <div className="course_section">
      <div className="section_button_container">
        {sectionBtns.map(({ id, icon_class, name, btn_name }) => {
          return (
            <div className="course_btns" key={id}>
              <button
                type="button"
                className={
                  [
                    "section_btn",
                    tab === id ? "active" : null // <-- conditionally apply active class
                  ]
                    .filter(Boolean)
                    .join(" ")
                }
                name={btn_name}
                id={`button${id}`}
                onClick={() => openTab(id)} // <-- set tab to button id
              >
                <i className={icon_class}></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                {name}
              </button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>

      <div className="data_container">
        {tab === 1 && (
          <>
            <h1>Video Section</h1>
          </>
        )}
        {tab === 2 && (
          <>
            <h1>Lab Section</h1>
          </>
        )}
        {tab === 3 && (
          <>
            <h1>Note Section</h1>
          </>
        )}
        {tab === 4 && (
          <>
            <h1>Chat Section</h1>
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit button-onclick-function-active-class-not-correctly-performing]